# Not able to create a file . I'm getting error "No such file or directory"

Tags: permissions, mount

I'm not able to create a file . I'm getting error "No such file or directory"

```bash
pranjal@pranjal:~$ cd /mnt
pranjal@pranjal:/mnt$ ls
0A08588908587623  ntfs2  ubu
pranjal@pranjal:/mnt$ cd ubu
pranjal@pranjal:/mnt/ubu$ ls
'CP practice'                learningPython
'Desktop Files'              LeetCodeDoneQuestions.txt
 dpLeetCodeSectionWise.txt  '$RECYCLE.BIN'
 GraphCodes                 'System Volume Information'
 javaScript                 'Ubuntu Files'
'Krrish Paper'
pranjal@pranjal:/mnt/ubu$ touch abc.txt
touch: cannot touch 'abc.txt': No such file or directory
pranjal@pranjal:/mnt/ubu$
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening ? I'm already in `/mnt/ubu` and it's saying that no such file or directory ??

I already did `mkdir -p /mnt/ubu` but still same error

PS : Actually before this something went wrong and my partiition /mnt/ubu became just readable . It was showing this error "ErrorReadOnlyFileSystem". So, I did "sudo mount -oremount,rw /mnt/ubu" i got write access . Because now it shows me a gui option to create a new file and not getting "ErrorReadOnlyFileSystem" but now this error is showing up

I've already looked for similar problems on stackExchange and on google but it hasn't helped me

Edit-> i'm using "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

Comment: You can't write to a read-only file system. It is read-only.

Comment: You haven't provided any specific OS/release details; except it relates to Ubuntu Touch (ie. a phone or tablet device running [Lorimi](https://ubports.com/) (*previously known as Ubuntu Touch*) which you may not have intended.

Comment: Please clarify your OS/release as you state both Ubuntu Touch *via tags* (ie. a phone/tablet OS based on Ubuntu) & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - they are different systems.

Answer (score -1):

FIXED

Ok so i fixed it with an old school trick. Since i have dual booted my PC .
I opened that partition with WINDOWS 10 and created an empty file.

Than rebooted and now it's working fine in Ubuntu too.

Windows generally repairs such problems automatically and it did this time too.

Comment: Knowing that you dual boot with Windows is an essential detail that you failed to mention in your question. Are you sure you don't have "Fast Startup" enabled? If you share a volume with Windows you need to have this disabled. Otherwise Windows will flag the shared volume and it can only be mounted read-only. Fast Startup is a hybrid suspend and doesn't allow the system to fully shut down. This also occurs if you suspend. I don't think you discovered an old school trick and neither did Windows fix this problem automatically.

Comment: @NmathNo i haven't enabled "Fast Startup" . Actually I needed a partition to only store data that I needed for both in Windows and Ubuntu . So, created "ubu" partition with ntfs . 
And later i figured out this configuration can work.
Unfortunately i couldn't get any documentation to do that . So, I had to do a lot hit and trial . But one thing is for sure i didn't enable "Fast Startup"
And yeah Windows repairs disks. I've done it so many times .Many times as a beginner i've messed up with  rights permission and what not. And windows automatically fixed those at boot time .

Comment: Fast Startup is already enabled. You have to disable it.  FYI: Windows has absolutely no capacity to fix problems in Ubuntu. Windows doesn't understand how to read or write to the file systems used by Ubuntu. Windows doesn't magically solve problems and is incapable of fixing problems in Ubuntu. The real problem is actually caused by how Windows shuts down.  The read only file system is caused by not shutting down Windows properly. Of course when Windows is rebooted, it will unlock the file system IT locked. No magic here. The problem will continue to occur until you disable fast startup.